# Jenkins how to force tasks to run even with failure in one of them?

Tags: java, jenkins, build

Hi I'm running some tasks using Jenkins. There I have 5 tasks to run sequentially like:

```
test --tests apptest.WP_RecuperarSenha.testTeste_recuperar_senha_e_logar 
test --tests apptest.WP_CadastroInvalido.testTeste_cadastro_campos_invalidos  
test --tests apptest.WP_CadastroEmBranco.testedecadastrobranco 
test --tests apptest.WP_InteracaoProduto.testeinteracaoproduto
```

I would like to know how to force Jenkins to keep running the build even, for example, if `test --tests apptest.WP_RecuperarSenha.testTeste_recuperar_senha_e_logar` fails. How to keep running it?

Comment: Do you use a pipeline job or freestyle? How do you run your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a free-style job you can use the conditional step plugin for each task and set each of the steps to always run.

If you utilize the pipeline plugin you can surround each task in a `try/catch` block and then inside the `catch` write `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'` (or `currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'` if it's more meaningful to you).

Comment: I'm using a free-style project. I'll search for that plugin